# PyDev/Eclipse/Python not showing all methods of a class

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev

Running Eclipse (Galileo) with PyDev.  I am trying to work with the module urllib2 and I've *just* started experimenting with it.  One of the tutorials I am going through says to call geturl() on my urllib2.urlopen() class.  So I did, and it worked as expected.

However, I was surprised when I tried to browse the class methods by using Eclipses handy-dandy "ctrl+space" shortcut it only gives me the private methods for what I think are a base class:

[image]

When I do `dir(page)`, I get all sorts of neat methods I can play with!

```
['__doc__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__repr__', 'close', 'code', 'fileno', 'fp', 'getcode', 'geturl', 'headers', 'info', 'msg', 'next', 'read', 'readline', 'readlines', 'url']
```

Is this an Eclipse problem?  Or a user error?  If I put this in IDLE, I can use IDLE's auto-completion feature to see what methods are available, but I can't get the same functionality to work with PyDev; I believe it is working on my work PC, but my home PC (the one I am at now) seems to be "not normal".

I have looked as best I could on Google/Stackoverflow, but I'm not sure which keywords will return the result that might help me understand what's going wrong here.  Any insight you can provide would be great!

(Python 2.6, running in a Debian (#!) virtual environment, windows7 host - if any of that matters)

NB:  I'm only developing on the Debian side, so I don't have eclipse on Win7.

**UPDATE1:**

To answer, "what does the browser end with if I scroll down?"  It ends with **subclasshook**.  See the photo below for what the bottom of the list looks like (it's all private , no methods).

[image]

**UPDATE2:**

As previous post suggested, I went into the preferences menu and checked the autocompletion tabs, and the interpreter preference tab, and nothing seems out of place (but then again, after reading the pydev autocompletion document, I'm not seeing anything about a 'firewall' or any indication that there is one.

However, I did another test, see the image below:

[image]

The auto-completion feature for `wx` works just fine.  Perhaps I misunderstood what was being told to me in previous posts, however, I am understanding that the reason I am seeing magic methods for my `page` class is because PyDev doesn't know what else to populate it with - so it's obviously confused.  I'm just not sure where to go from here.  I'll keep reading PyDev docs to see if I can figure out in the meantime.

And, I almost forgot - when I "hover" my mouse over urllib2.urlopen() in my code, it **does** show me the doc string.  Not sure if that provides any insight about this supposed broken functionality.

**UPDATE3:**

As per someones comment regarding "forced builtins" only auto-completing in PyDev, I went and added "urllib2" to the forced builtins under preferences.  Below is the image of what I am getting...

[image]

I have some new methods... but not the ones I expected (ie I am NOT seeing the ones I get from `__dict__` when I call `dir(page)`, specifically, geturl()).

Comment: Just a side note: Not all of those things are methods—e.g., `code` and `fp`, not to mention `__doc__` and `__module__`, are attributes. But more seriously: If you scroll the list in Eclipse, does it end with `__repr__`?

Comment: Also, are you showing us an interactive interpreter, or a file editor? Because in IDLE, I only get these completions from an interactive session; in a source editor, if I type `page.` and hit Tab, it'll complete whatever `page` is in the current interactive session, not whatever I defined it to in the source.

Comment: ah thank you for that correction, I just assumed they were all methods.  I added an update to your question about "what does it end with".

Comment: I believe I am doing this in the source editor... I don't have an "interactive interpreter" setup like I had in IDLE...  hmmm, Im worried Im describing this wrong and using the wrong vocabulary... I have the editor window up top - where my source code is (it's a standard pydev perspective), down below I have a "tab" that says _Console_, in that window, is all my output from Python.  My error is being observed in the window up top - what I am calling the source window.  Does that make sense =/?

Comment: This isn't your problem, but I think you're a bit confused by the word "method". You are seeing plenty of methods (e.g., `__ne__` and `__reduce__`), and you're missing plenty of things that aren't methods (e.g., `code` and `fp`). What you're seeing also includes a lot of stuff that is in the `dir` but not in the `__dict__`, as well as things that come from a base class. I think a better way to describe what you are and aren't seeing is that you're only seeing the magic methods (both standard and non-standard), those surrounded by two underscores.

Comment: There is an interactive interpreter in PyDev, it's just not the thing that pops up as the main window by default, the way it is in IDLE. Anyway, my point is that you may be making an unfair comparison between PyDev and IDLE: IDLE's interactive interpreter can use the real object to do completion dynamically, while PyDev's editor window has to sort of guess at what `page` is going to be at runtime, which IDLE's editor window doesn't even attempt to do.

Comment: One unlikely but not impossible possibility: Is PyDev set up to default to, say, CPython 3.3 or Jython 2.1 or something else that doesn't have a `urllib2.urlopen`? If so, it would have no idea what the type of `page` is and wouldn't be able to suggest any attributes specific to its type. I think (it's been a while) that if you leave the default settings alone, you can force it to use the right interpreter by adding a `#!` line to the top of the script (`#! /usr/bin/python` if that's where your CPython 2.6 is).

Comment: fair enough - I /do/ have to run whatever module I want to autocomplete with (which then loads the classes I am working with) for the tab completion to even work.  But, is not possible then to get the same functionality out of pydev?  If I didn't run dir(page) (where page = urllib2.urlopen() in this case) I wouldn't have known what else was there... is there an alternative method I should be using to find out what attributes and methods a class has?

Comment: alright, Ill give that a try (#! /usr/bin/python).

Comment: Again, I'm a bit out of date with PyDev, but I remember one useful tip to test whether it's confused: If you point at an object, you should see the docstring for its class in a popup, and you should be able to… hit some key or right-click or something to get to the class's definition. If that isn't working, none of the fancier stuff will work.

Comment: From the last update, it looks what you'd expect if you typed `page = urllib.urlopen` instead of `page = urllib.urlopen(url)`. Attributes like `func_code`, etc., only exist on functions, and the thing `urlopen` returns is definitely not a function! Something is confused somewhere… but I have no idea what. Obviously it won't help you if I tell you that a clean PyDev install on my Mac against the system Python 2.7.2 handles `urlopen` properly, because that gives us no clue why your PyDev install on your linux box doesn't…

Comment: Well if it's working in your version of Eclipse, that helps me narrow down the problem.  Thanks I'll keep looking and once I have an update I'll come back.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those are Python's "magic methods":

http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

They're special methods you can define on any object to give it custom behavior. Most Python IDEs know not to show them, but Eclipse is being especially helpful.

Comment: hmm, interesting.  Hadn't really made the distinction of magic methods versus "non magic methods" before.  Thanks for that.  Do you have any clues as to why Eclipse is not showing me the rest of the class methods/attributes?  Like in this case geturl()?

Comment: I think this is just the generic list of magic methods that Eclipse assumes any class will support, when it can guess that this is an object of class type but can't guess which one… (And there are no non-magic methods that all classes are expected to support.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is a fundamental one with a dynamic language like Python: your IDE has no way of knowing what type of object your `page` variable refers to. To do that, it would have to know what type `urlopen()` returns. And there's no way to know that without calling it! It may not even return the same type each time you call it, in which case, what class's methods should it show you?

IDEs can make some guesses, but when these guesses fail, you get results like what you're seeing. It knows you have an object, because everything's an object, so it shows you methods of `object`.

Comment: The IDE does have a way to tell—by a combination of guessing, and running various bits of code in a subshell. See http://pydev.org/manual_adv_complctx.html for details.

Comment: @abarnert: The IDE uses a subshell only for built-ins, otherwise code completion only works for things that are defined in the same scope (according to the documentation in your link) -- so I think kindall may be right.

Comment: @martineau, you might be on to something here - I added urllib2 to the "forced builtins" - see my Update3 - but I didn't get everything I expected when I ctrl-space (auto-complete).  Any thoughts?

Comment: @martineau: No, "defined in the same scope" includes knowing how to follow imports. It would be pretty useless otherwise. I believe it usually tries to find the imports by manually traversing the configured PYTHONPATH, etc., without firing up a subshell… but regardless, if it's configured right, it can definitely follow imports.

Comment: Interesting, in your Update3 it looks like it thinks it's a function. My only other thought at this point is that the IDE isn't configured properly -- so I can only suggest reading about the Preferences setting at the link abarnert provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the documentation](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_complctx.html):

> It's important to note that your interpreter must be properly configured for the code-completion to work, and for getting the builtins, PyDev spawns a shell, so, having a firewall can prevent the code-completion from working if it's blocking the communication from eclipse to that shell.

In other words, you have to go into the Preferences and set both the "Code Completion" settings and the "Interpreter - Python" settings, and make sure Eclipse can start a subshell and communicate with it over a socket without a firewall or anything else getting in the way.

My guess is that, of those things, your interpreter setup is most likely to be wrong. Even if your Python is in the usual `/usr/bin/python` location, you may have PyDev set up to look for, say, `/usr/bin/python3`, or `python26`, or "don't guess, always use the #! line or a project-specific setting", or you've installed Python in a per-user location instead of system-wide, or who knows what.

See what you have in the "Interpreter - Python" prefs page, and see if you can run Python the way Eclipse expects to run it. If not, it will not be able to do any command-line completion except the basic stuff that's built in. (As I said elsewhere, I believe that means it can guess that `page` is of some class type, but it can't tell what type, so it will guess all the standard magic methods that nearly any class object has, and nothing else.)